# Adding a column to the typo3 pages table calculated from the result of "strip_tags(title)"

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x, typo3-tca

In my typo3 installation, the page title field allows HTML and I'm trying to add a hidden "title_TagStripped" field to the pages table be able to include this new field to [Pages][ctrl][searchFields].

I'm a bit confused whether I need to create a TCA override for a passthrough type or a user type field or something else. My first try was a input type with an custom eval function but I don't know if it's possible to pass another field value to the evaluateFieldValue() function.

If anybody has pointers for this typo3 noobie...

Thanks

Comment: First, it is a really bad idea to allow arbitrary HTML for editors as this can provoke security issues.
To your question: You can add a custom DataHandler hook (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Typo3CoreEngine/Database/Index.html), for example "processDatamap_preProcess" (https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/11.5/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/DataHandling/DataHandler.php#L888) or "processDatamap_postProcess", where you can adapt data before storing into database.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a passthru field for it is not advisable, likely the search would be unreliable if the field is not shown in the backend.
I'd create a simple input field (like the title field) with the difference that the new field can't be edited.

Concerning the functional implementation you have several options

- populating only if a record is saved.
- populating by JavaScript if the title field is changed.
- perhaps some other solution with ajax if there is some reason.

So you had to specify which option you prefer.